# normalizer of a cyclic group

Tags: group-theory, permutations, cyclic-groups, normal-subgroups

I have a cyclic permutation group G=<(123456)> what is normalizer of this group?

the normalizer a subset A of a group G such that:

$$N_{G}(A)= (g \in G s.t \;\;\; gag^{-1} \in A , \;\; \forall a \in A)$$

Comment: Normalizer in what supergroup? $S_6$ ?

Comment: @lhf sorry in S_{6}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For any $\sigma\in S_6$, we have $$\sigma(123456)\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma(1)\sigma(2)\sigma(3)\sigma(4)\sigma(5)\sigma(6)),$$ where $\sigma(i)$ is $\sigma$ applied to $i$.

Comment: I read somewhere for cyclic group (<1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8>) subgroup of $S-{8}$, normalizer is infinite , I can't understand that

Comment: how normalizer is infinite for finite group?

Comment: What you have read is wrong, @sherek_66. [The normaliser is always a subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1407012/104041) and for any $H\le G$, $$|H|\le |G|.$$

Comment: please see page 6, example 2.6 case when d=p of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.01152.pdf

Comment: Regardless as to what that example says, @sherek_66, any subgroup of a finite group is finite; indeed, if $h\in H\le G$, then $h\in G$.