# Small trouble proving that the normalizer is a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm doing the following exercise on Clark's "Elements of Abstract Algebra":

> [image]

I did almost all of it but then I have to prove that $N(H)$ is a subgroup of $G$. I proved that if $a,b\in N(H)$ then $ab\in N(H)$. It remains to prove that if $a\in N(H)$ then $a^{-1}\in N(H)$, I think this boils down to proving that if $H^a=H$, then $H^{a^{-1}}=H$.

I know that vecause $H=H^a$, all the elements of $H^a$ are of the form $axa^{-1}$ and the elements of $H^{a^{-1}}$ are of the form $a^{-1}xa$. I guessed I have to write $a^{-1}xa$  in terms of products of $axa^{-1}$ (since $H^a$ is a subgroup) and substitutions such as $y=axa^{-1}$ where $aya^{-1}$ but this didn't work.

**Disclaimer:** I am aware that this is a classic question that has been asked before but in my googling, everything was written in a way a bit different than the one I found in my book.

Comment: Note  $(axa^{-1})^{-1}=ax^{-1}a^{-1}$

Comment: From your definition elements in $H^a$ are not of the form $axa^{-1}$. It is all $x\in G$ with $axa^{-1} \in H$

Comment: I still think that [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1407012/proof-that-normalizer-and-center-are-subgroups) answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

Let's use the subgroup criterion.   We need to show that for any $x,y\in N(H)$ that $xy^{-1}\in N(H)$.

Now $xy^{-1}H(xy^{-1})^{-1}=xy^{-1}Hyx^{-1}=xHx^{-1}=H$.

Thus $N(H)$ is a subgroup.

Comment: What allows you to simplify$\;xy^{-1}Hyx^{-1}\;$to$\;xHx^{-1}$?

Comment: @quasi $y^{-1}Hy=H$

Comment: How do you know$\;y^{-1}Hy=H$?

Comment: @quasi because $H=yHy^{-1}$ by $y\in N(H)$.

Comment: Yes, I see now -- thanks.